# Vandermonde determinant and the Nullstellensatz

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials

This is the Vandermonde matrix:

$V (x_1, ..., x_n) =\left [ \begin{matrix}
    1 & x_1&x_1^2&...&x_1^{n-1} \\
    1 & x_2&x_2^2&...&x_2^{n-1} \\
    1 & x_3&x_3^2&...&x_3^{n-1} \\
    \vdots & \vdots&\vdots&...&\vdots \\
    1 & x_n&x_n^2&...&x_n^{n-1} \\
   \end{matrix} \right ]$

Suppose we didn't know that $\text{det }V(x_1,\dots,x_n)=\prod_{1\leq i<j\leq n}(x_j-x_i)$. It is easy to see that both polynomials vanish on exactly the same subset of $\mathbb{C}^n$, which is:

$V=\{(z_1,\dots,z_n)\in\mathbb{C}^n | z_i=z_j\text{ for some }i\neq j\}$

Is it possible to use the Nullstellsatz to prove that they generate the same principal ideal in $\mathbb{C}[x_1,\dots,x_n]$?

Comment: Nullstellensatz gives you $\det V(\vec x)\in\sqrt{I}=(\prod_{i<j} (x_j-x_i))$ but you have $\deg\det V=\frac12n(n-1)=\deg \prod_{i<j} (x_j-x_i)$.

Comment: @user10354138 If $I=(\prod_{i<j}(x_j-x_i))$, why is $\sqrt{I}=I$? Is this explanation correct: that $(x_j-x_i)$ is irreducible, so if it divides a power of a polynomial $p$, then it must divide $p$

Comment: That is one way.  Remember to use $\mathbb{C}[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ UFD.

Comment: You don't need the Nullstellensatz, just basic commutative algebra to deduce the determinant along with your observation with the roots.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I'll think some more about it, thanks